# Fatal error: Call to a member function check_capabilities() on a non-object

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've written this code in functions.php to add a section to my theme personalization.
But when I want to open "localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/customize.php?theme=eye-theme" to see my result, I see this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `check_capabilities()` on a non-object in     C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-customize-control.php on line 233

This is my **functions.php**:

```
<?php

function eyetheme_register_theme_customizer($wp_customizer) {

    $wp_customizer->add_section(
        'eyetheme_display_options',
        array(
            'title'     => 'Display Options',
            'priority'  => 200
        )
    );

    $wp_customizer->add_setting(
        'eyetheme_link_color',
        array(
            'default'   => '#000000',
            'transport' => 'postMessage'
       )
    );

    $wp_customizer->add_control(
        'eyetheme_link_control',
        array(
            'section'   => 'eyetheme_display_options',
            'label'     => 'Link Color',
            'type'      => 'text'
       )
    );

}
add_action('customize_register', 'eyetheme_register_theme_customizer');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to update $wp_customizer->add_setting() method and "settings" parameter in the arguments for $wp_customizer->add_control().

i.e. In your example,

```
$wp_customizer->add_setting(
  'link_color',
  array(
    'default'   => '#000',
    'transport' => 'postMessage'
  )
);
$wp_customizer->add_control(  
  'eyetheme_link_control',  
  array(  
    'section'   => 'eyetheme_display_options',  
    'label'     => 'Link Color',  
    'type'      => 'text',  
    'settings'  => 'link_color'  
  )
)
```

Try this code...